# Material UI Textfield prints incorrectly

Tags: html, reactjs, printing, material-ui, textarea

I'm trying to print page of react app using `window.print()`. Everything print correctly, but not Textfield (from Material UI). It works when I dont have too many text lines. But when i write a lot of text it looks like this (print preview):
[image]

And this is code:

```
 <form autoComplete="off" className="subsection">
    <TextField
      error={controlHasError(
        props.errors,
        'MetodyWyceny',
        props.data.MetodyWyceny,
      )}
      name="MetodyWyceny"
      label="Opis"
      multiline
      variant="outlined"
      title={props.data.MetodyWyceny}
      defaultValue={props.data.MetodyWyceny}
      onBlur={(e) => props.onSetSectionData('MetodyWyceny', e.target.value)}
    />
  </form>

  .subsection {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
  }
```

And I have this code to style textareas (multiline Textfield is textarea actually):

```
  textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

So, what I can do to print this component correctly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there are mistakes in your usage or TextField, https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/. it doesn't have "title" prop.

verify, props.data.MetodyWyceny by logging it and see if it has any leading spaces.
what i mean is the default value you are setting itself might have many spaces before actual content, it is the only explanation for your output

Comment: I deleted title prop, not result. I logged data, there no white spaces :(